# How to Cloning Gitlab Project by Using Hook?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, git-clone

i have my own gitlab server. I had created new-project, and i want to clone that project repositories to gitrepo on my local machine after doing first commit, can i do that automatically by using hook? if yes which hook i must use?

regards

Answer (score 0):

check webhook decumentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html
and gitlabform tool
https://github.com/egnyte/gitlabform

or simple
https://github.com/shawn-sterling/gitlab-webhook-receiver